# In MATLAB, how to annotate a figure with an image?

Tags: image, matlab, annotations

I'd like to overlay an image on top of my figure at a specific point.. 
e.g. I want "cherry.png" [24px X 24px] drawn at the normalized point [0.20, 0.50] of a 600px X 600px figure.
I have access to the Image Processing toolbox, and I'm aware of "imread()", however it is unclear to me how to overlay at a specific point. Any ideas/references that I should check out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your 24-by-24 pixel image to be *centered* at the normalized point `(0.2,0.5)` (equivalent to `(120,300)` in pixels), then you can create an [axes object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes.html) that is 24-by-24 pixels and centered at your point and add an image to the axes with the [IMAGE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/image.html) function. For example:

```
img = imread('cherry.png');  %# Read the data from your image file
hFigure = figure('Position',[100 100 600 600]);  %# Make the figure window
hAxes = axes('Parent',hFigure,...          %# Add the axes to the figure
             'Units','pixels',...          %#   with units of pixels
             'Position',[108 288 24 24]);  %#   so the position is easy to define
hImage = image(img,'Parent',hAxes);  %# Plot the image
set(hAxes,'Visible','off');          %# Turn the axes visibility off
```

Note that when I loaded the image data using [IMREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imread.html) I assumed it was a 3-D [RGB image](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f2-10709.html#f2-12468). If it's an [indexed image](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f2-10709.html#f2-155) you'll have to get the additional color map output from [IMREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imread.html) so you can [convert the indexed image to an RGB image](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ind2rgb.html).